# What is TCACHE?

Tags: c, malloc, heap-memory, glibc, heap-corruption

I'm playing around with binary exploitation on linux for a long time, and recently I'm writing some heap exploitation notes based on **ptmalloc**, so I go back to view some payloads from past security challenges I've solved and astonishingly they didn't work anymore.

For example, the basic double free corruption (not fastbin)

```
char *chunk1 = malloc(0xc0);
free(chunk1);
free(chunk1);
```

I expected to see something like

```
*** Error in `main': double free or corruption (top): 0x0000000000c85010 ***
```

But no, there's nothing happen and the program exit normally.

For that I go to check the glibc source code corresponding to my machine - `Debian GLIBC 2.27-2`, and found very difference in `malloc.c`.

```
void *
__libc_malloc (size_t bytes)
{     
...
#if USE_TCACHE
  /* int_free also calls request2size, be careful to not pad twice.  */
  size_t tbytes;
  checked_request2size (bytes, tbytes);
  size_t tc_idx = csize2tidx (tbytes);

  MAYBE_INIT_TCACHE ();

  DIAG_PUSH_NEEDS_COMMENT;
  if (tc_idx < mp_.tcache_bins
      /*&& tc_idx < TCACHE_MAX_BINS*/ /* to appease gcc */
      && tcache
      && tcache->entries[tc_idx] != NULL)
    {
      return tcache_get (tc_idx);
    }
  DIAG_POP_NEEDS_COMMENT;
#endif
```

the `USE_TCACHE` also appears in many other places.

then I went back my program above and found `chunk1` was not placed in `small bin` but in `tcache_entry`.

what's the purpose of `TCACHE` ? I search a lot and still confused.

Comment: A quick google search hints at `per thread cache`. I'm guessing that this `malloc` implementation keeps a smallish pool of preallocated blocks of various sizes for each thread. That way many calls can be satisfied without locks.

Comment: Welcome to the world of exploits.  Each exploit has to be tailored to the specific implementation of `malloc()` — different implementations have different vulnerabilities and what works for one won't necessarily work for others.

Comment: Isn't the real question why the tool you have used doesn't detect the double free any more? (Probably because the malloc() was served from tcache)

Comment: @Flow no, actually I had figured out how tcache exploitation works, in short it discards many security checks since glibc 2.26 (like the case in my question), a lot of exploits become more powerful.

Answer (score 7):

The Thread Local Cache (tcache) is a performance optimization in glibc. Unfortunately, it comes at the expense of security and make some attacks much easier, as you have since discovered.

From https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/MallocInternals#Thread_Local_Cache_.28tcache.29

> While this malloc is aware of multiple threads, that's pretty much the extent of its awareness - it knows there are multiple threads. There is no code in this malloc to optimize it for NUMA architectures, coordinate thread locality, sort threads by core, etc. It is assumed that the kernel will handle those issues sufficiently well.
>
> Each thread has a thread-local variable that remembers which arena it last used. If that arena is in use when a thread needs to use it the thread will block to wait for the arena to become free. If the thread has never used an arena before then it may try to reuse an unused one, create a new one, or pick the next one on the global list.
>
> Each thread has a per-thread cache (called the tcache) containing a small collection of chunks which can be accessed without needing to lock an arena. These chunks are stored as an array of singly-linked lists, like fastbins, but with links pointing to the payload (user area) not the chunk header. Each bin contains one size chunk, so the array is indexed (indirectly) by chunk size. Unlike fastbins, the tcache is limited in how many chunks are allowed in each bin (tcache_count). If the tcache bin is empty for a given requested size, the next larger sized chunk is not used (could cause internal fragmentation), instead the fallback is to use the normal malloc routines i.e. locking the thread's arena and working from there.